# Kafka consumer_group name

Tags: apache-kafka

I am new to Kafka but have watched several youtube videos on the subject.
What is the value of more than one consumer being in the same consumer_group, if it will
potentially prevent them from getting all messages sent by a Publisher to a given topic?

It seems that selecting a unique customer_group name per consumer is the solution?

Comment: Unique name per app, where you run multiple instances of an app for scaling out parallel consumption

Answer (score 1):

If you choose a unique customer group name per consumer, each consumer will consume all the records sent to kafka.

If all consumers have the same consumer group name, they will share the consumption between them. For example, if you have three partitions in your kafka, and you have three consumers working at the same pace, they each deal with a unique partition. If you run less consumers, one consumer may be assigned multiple partitions.